# AdView doesn't show ads at the bottom of the linear layout layout -Why So?

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, adview

I'm trying to show admob adview at the bottom of the screen but it doesn't work. It shows ad below the text if the text is short (doesn't need to scroll) , but if the text is long (need to scroll) the adview doesn't show at all.
I want to show the adview at the bottom of my screen no matter how long or short the text is. I have been at this for hours but couldn't figure out to make it work.

Here is my Activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    tools:context=".activities.DetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="1.46dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWordDetail"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/textToSpeech"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/text_to_speech"
            android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_volume"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBookmark"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_bookmark"
            android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/viewColor"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
            android:elevation="1.46dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWordDefinition"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewDetail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_detail">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one new attributes *android:layout_weight="1"*  and Modify height of scroll view as below.

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

So final attributes set of scrollview looks like,

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works flawlessly but is there any way i can remove this line https://imgur.com/a/XKD9MXM

Comment: It seems the background property ***android:background="@color/backgroundColor"*** causing the issue. So you can try by removing it from root LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="680dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWordDetail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/textToSpeech"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_volume"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBookmark"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/add_bookmark"
                android:background="?actionBarItemBackground"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
                android:elevation="1.46dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvWordDefinition"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>




    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_ad_detail">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```